# How to have the first \gls in a float \caption entry show as \glsfirst

Tags: glossaries

I have multiple float environments (`scheme`, `figure` and `table`) with respective `\caption`'s that I would like to be able to reuse (I `\include` floats from another file so they do not clutter my text sections). An issue arose when using `\gls` entries where for some documents I would like the first entry of an entry to be `\glsfirst` and the remaining uses to be of `\gls`.

Ideally, I would like to just use `\gls` in all of my schemes/figures/tables and define a command that allows the first `\gls` of each unique entry to act as `\glsfirst` but my attempts have failed. For some documents, it makes sense to just let `\gls` be `\gls` and for others the first `\gls` needs defining within the float on first use. At first, I tried:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\let\gls\glsfirst}
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure*}{\let\gls\glsfirst}
```

Using `figure` as an example. This did not work as it lasted beyond the first use of `\gls` (I don't know why I even tried this). Then I tried:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\glsresetall}
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure*}{\glsresetall}
```

This worked within the caption but then extended beyond the float environment into the main document text that followed the `\include{float}` (for example), I am not sure if `\AtBeginEnvironment` acts inside or outside of the float environment.

Is there a way to have the first unique `\gls` entry behave as `\glsfirst` and for it to only apply to within their respective float environment please? This can be done manually by just using `\glsfirst` for each term but I wouldn't mind each float being able to be reused in different documents if needed.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}   % For \autocap
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{adh}
    {%
    name={ADH},
    description={Alcohol dehydrogenase},
    user1={\autocap{a}lcohol dehydrogenase},
    first={\glsuseri{\glslabel} (\glsname{\glslabel})},
    }

\newglossaryentry{vspm}
    {%
    name={VSPM},
    description={Very small polar molecule},
    first={\autocap{v}ery small polar molecule (VSPM)},
    }

\begin{document}

Foo \gls{adh} and \gls{vspm}.

\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{Foo bar \gls{adh} baz foo \gls{vspm}. Foo bar \gls{adh} baz foo \gls{vspm}.}
\end{figure}

Foo \gls{adh} and \gls{vspm}.

\end{document}
```

How it currently looks:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

A workaround (as a method using `\patchcmd` from the `etoolbox` was not working with either `\caption` or `\@caption`) involves just setting in the preamble

```
\let\cccc\glslocalresetall
```

and putting `\cccc` (or whatever you call it) before the text in a caption like

```
\caption{\cccc Foo bar  baz foo \gls{vspm}. \gls{vspm}.}
```

It is surprising how difficult it appears to be to reset glossaries automatically in float captions when this is fairly typical (unless I have overlooked a setting or something in the newer `glossaries-extra` package).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{biblatex}   % For \autocap
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{adh}
    {%
    name={ADH},
    description={Alcohol dehydrogenase},
    user1={\autocap{a}lcohol dehydrogenase},
    first={\glsuseri{\glslabel} (\glsname{\glslabel})},
    }

\newglossaryentry{vspm}
    {%
    name={VSPM},
    description={Very small polar molecule},
    first={\autocap{v}ery small polar molecule (VSPM)},
    }

\let\cccc\glslocalresetall

\begin{document}

\noindent Foo \gls{adh} and \gls{vspm}.

\begin{figure}[t]
\caption{\cccc Foo bar  baz foo \gls{vspm}. \gls{vspm}.}
\end{figure}

Foo \gls{adh} and \gls{vspm}.

\end{document}
```